# sublime hangs terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext2

I am using sublime text 2 for ROR development and i have a problem that it hangs the terminal window when opened through it.

Does anyone know of manner of preventing the "hanging"?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

How are you opening ST2?  If you are using the `-w` flag, then ST2 will wait until you close the editor until the terminal prompt is restored.

Comment: I created symbolic link and just use it using "subl" typed in the command line.